# I can't in any way include css in my theme using functions.php

Tags: functions

I can't in any way include css in my theme using `functions.php`

I tried to include css using the link tag, but it only loads it on the first page, then when I go to open other pages (for example the example page) I don't load any style, how can I do it?

this is the code:

```php
function theme_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'font', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Comment: Does the tag not appear on the other pages? Which file is this code located in? Are there any errors or warnings in your browser dev tools console? Is this a child theme?

Comment: Is this a child theme? If so, you probably want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to point to child theme stylesheets. `get_template_directory_uri()` pulls from the parent theme.

Comment: Does your theme have a header.php file with the `wp_head()` function inside the `<head>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

In your first enqueue type get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri
For stylesheet its functions.php requires get_stylesheet_directory_uri()